# MemoryStream object throwing System.OutOfMemoryException

Tags: c#, memory, out-of-memory, messagebox

I've this piece of code which works fine in my machine but throws `System.OutOfMemoryException` in another machine. I'm just trying to initialize `MemoryStream` object and then write the contents of `xDoc` in it.
`xDoc` is an object of datatype `XDocument` and in my machine I can see that the length of stream when written with the contents of `xDoc` is `58070847`.

```
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
xDoc.Save(stream);
stream.Position = 0;
using (var sr = new StreamReader(stream))
{
    strXml = sr.ReadToEnd();
}
```

There are several questions for `System.OutOfMemoryException` here but they don't answer my problem.

Things that I tried :

- All the `constructors` for `MemoryStream`.
- [MemoryTributary.cs](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/348590/A-replacement-for-MemoryStream)

  MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
  Thread.Sleep(4000); //Added this because of last point.
  xDoc.Save(stream);
  stream.Position = 0;
  using (var sr = new StreamReader(stream))
  {
  strXml = sr.ReadToEnd();
  }

None of the above worked but strangely the below piece of code works and I wonder how.

```
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
MessageBox.Show("Loading data"); //Added this for reference while testing and strangely doesn't throw any error!!
xDoc.Save(stream);
stream.Position = 0;
using (var sr = new StreamReader(stream))
{
    strXml = sr.ReadToEnd();
}
```

I wish to understand why adding a `MessageBox` statement works

Thanks

Comment: *Where* is it throwing the exception? In `Save` or in `ReadToEnd`?

Comment: It's unclear why a `MemoryStream` is involved at all here when you should be able to just do `strXml = xDoc.ToString()`?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I understand that it can be done via the simple line that you suggested but I'm more interested in what I'm doing wrong in the given piece of code so that I understand C# better.

Comment: @JonSkeet In `Save`

Comment: Why do people do this? Who in their right mind thinks it's OK to hurl 60 MB of XML to a piece of code? Your code will need a multiple thereof in contiguous memory to save the string, the byte array within the memory stream, and so on. You're probably running as 32 bit process. The solution is not to switch to 64 bit, but to slap the person who sends you this XML.

Answer (score 1):

You're using large, contiguous amounts of memory to hold a serialised xml document in memory. There's no need for this. `xDoc` can serialise straight to/from disk, and will hold a much smaller binary representation.

The probable reason that `ToString()` works whereas `Save()` doesn't, is because `MemoryStream` will double its buffer each time the stream passes the end of buffer. So it's not just one 60MB contiguous memory block you're reserving, it's multiple blocks that double in size each time up to 60MB. These will be on the large object heap that does not get compacted in the same way the normal heap.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, just one more follow up question : why does it work in my machine and not in another machine which has all the same configuration.

Comment: All depends on how much memory the machine has, what else is running, what state the managed heap is in etc.

Comment: Even `ToString()` at times throws exception so is there an optimised way to initialise `strXml` ?

Comment: The problem is holding the entirety of the serialised document in memory at once. Do you actually *need* it all in memory? XDocument,Save() has an overload that takes a stream. Can you stream to disk or network instead?